# Expectation of minimum set of i.i.d random stopping times with the same distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

What is the expectation of the minimum set of n i.i.d random stopping times?
is it \frac{T}{n}

Comment: What is the distribution of the i.i.d. random stopping times?

Comment: a general distribution. Does E(min(r1,r2,…rn))=E(r)/n  holds for any distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Not only is that answer not true in general, offhand, I can't think of *any* distribution of the stopping times (defined to be a distribution that is zero on $r < 0$) that would make

$E(\min(r_1, r_2, \ldots r_n)) = \frac{E(r)}{n}$

hold for all positive integer $n$.